# Unable to create ON DELETE SET NULL constraint using Code First Migrations

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Up to now we used a simple DbInitializer class for our EF Code First Context thus:

```
Friend Class DbInitializer
    Inherit DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges(Of MyContext)

    Public Overrides Sub InitializeDatabase(context As MyContext)
        MyBase.InitializeDatabase(context)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Seed(context as MyContext)
        context.Database.ExecuteSql("ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Competitions]" & _
                                   " DROP CONSTRAINT
                  [FK_dbo.Competitions_dbo.CompetitorLists_PreferredPairsListId]")

        context.Database.ExecuteSql("ALTER TABLE dbo.Competitions" & _
           " ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Competitions_dbo.CompetitorLists_PreferredPlayersListId]" & _
           " FOREIGN KEY ([PreferredPlayersListId])" & _
           " REFERENCES [dbo].[CompetitorLists] ([ID])" & _
           " ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE SET NULL")

End Sub
```

The `Seed` method created a foreign key with an `ON DELETE SET NULL` constraint for the foreign key.

Now we are migrating to Code First Migrations and changed the `DbInitializer`thus:

```
Friend Class DbInitializer
    Inherits MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion(Of MyContext, Migrations.Configuration)

    <TraceAspect>
    Public Overrides Sub InitializeDatabase(context As MyContext)
        MyBase.InitializeDatabase(context)
    End Sub

End Class
```

The `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`class does not have a `Seed` method so I am looking for a place to put the `ALTER DATABASE` SQL commands. The `UP`method of the first Migrations seemed the logical spot. So I changed the `context.Database.ExecuteSQLCommand` to the shorter `SQL()` method that is used for the Migrations:

The code below was pasted at the end of the first `Up` method that was called.

```
Sql("ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Competitions]" & _
   " DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Competitions_dbo.CompetitorLists_PreferredPairsListId]")

Sql("ALTER TABLE dbo.Competitions" & _
         " ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Competitions_dbo.CompetitorLists_PreferredPlayersListId]" & _
         " FOREIGN KEY ([PreferredPlayersListId])" & _
         " REFERENCES [dbo].[CompetitorLists] ([ID])" & _
         " ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE SET NULL")
```

But no luck: the code is passed when I mark the lines in the debugger, but after the `Up` method concludes I get an Exception stating that

> FK_dbo.Competitions_dbo.CompetitorLists_PreferredPlayersListId is not a constraint. Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

Of previous errors there are none...

Mind, the Exception is not thrown *on* the SQL method, but *later on*.

I googled this and one of the causes I could find was that the Entity Framework changed naming conventions between versions. That is not the problem here: I checked that when I omit droppinge and adding the constraint it is created by EF with the same name.

An other cause can be that the constraint does in fact not exist yet. That would mean that the  `SQL`methods are executed *before* the other code in the `Up` method, despite it being physically the last code present.

So, what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> An other cause can be that the constraint does in fact not exist yet. That would mean that the SQLmethods are executed before the other code in the Up method, despite it being physically the last code present.

It seems that this supposition is correct: seemingly the operations defined in an `Up` method are not executed top-down.

If I create an empty migration using Add-Migration and out the `SQL` methods there, it works.